# Torque/Rotation & Sliding with Slipping

Tags: kinematics, rotational-dynamics, torque

> A student holds one end of a thread, which is wrapped around a cylindrical spool, as shown above. The student then drops the spool from a height h above the floor, and the thread unwinds as it falls. The spool has a mass M and a radius R, and the thread has negligible mass. The spool can be approximated as a solid cylinder of moment
>   of inertia I = 1 MR2. Express your answers in terms of M, R, h, and fundamental constants.
>
> At time t = 0, the spinning spool lands on the floor without bouncing and comes free from the thread. It continues to spin, but slips on the floor’s surface while doing so. Assume a constant coefficient of sliding friction m.
>
> (c) Calculate the angular velocity of the spool as a function of time t.

Could someone explain to me why the torque caused by the sliding friction decreases the angular velocity. In my mind, I'm seeing the spool rolling counterclockwise towards the left, in which case the sliding friction would act towards the right, causing a counterclockwise torque, increasing the angular velocity. Using common sense, I know the angular velocity would decrease, but in physics terms, why??

Comment: *... as shown above* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinetic friction always acts to decrease the relative motion between two surfaces.

If the spool is spinning counterclockwise (as we watch one end), that means the point of contact (at the bottom of the spool) is moving rapidly to the right.  Friction acts to decrease this relative motion and creates a force to left (a clockwise torque) slowing the angular velocity.

Answer (score 1):

When the spool hits the ground there is relative movement between the spool and the ground at their point of contact and so a frictional force $\vec F_{\rm kinetic}$ acts as shown in the left hand diagram.

[image]

The frictional force acts in such a direction as to reduce the relative movement between the two surfaces in contact.

You can think of that frictional  force as doing two things:

- acting on the spool to increase the velocity of the centre of mass of
  the spool
- providing an anticlockwise torque on the spool to reduce the angular
  speed of the spool $\Omega$.

This combination will eventually increase the translation speed to $v$ and decrease the rotational speed to $\omega$ (right hand diagram) so that the no slip condition $v=r\omega$ is satisfied.

When this happens there is no relative movement between the spoon and the ground at their foint of contact and if the ground is horizontal then no frictional force will need to act.